# Error when convert password to hash in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm creating a website using angular js and node js. i used mongodb as database . i want to store password after converting to hash value. i used this code and it is not working properly.

```
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

 module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
 User.findById(id,callback);
 }

 module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
 const query = {username:username}
 User.findOne(query, callback);
 }

 module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){
 bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
   hash(newUser.password, salt, (err)=> {
        if(err) throw err;
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save();
    });
});
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working properly'? Do you get an error? Does the hash not work? Does it not compile? Can you not login? Do you not see the hash in de db? something else? Should we guess?

Comment: not storing any value in database. and also will not occur any error in cmd. i think error is in this code part. but i do not know how it is happened.

Comment: Looking at the code, these are declarations for functions. How and where do you call the functions? Can you use debugging?